# Angular Route Resolver executing multiple times with rapid clicking

Tags: angular, rxjs

In Angular 11, Is there a way to prevent the route resolver from firing multiple times when clicking on a link rapidly?

I created a stackblitz demo below. If you open the stackblitz browser panel in a separate tab and inspect the Network requests you will see multiple API calls being made when rapidly clicking on the navigation with a route resolver. Adding a `debounceTime()` doesn't seem to help also.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-route-resolve-service-ftocrp?file=src/app/api.service.ts

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

`app.component.html`

```html
<br />
<a routerLink="home">Home</a>
<br />
<a #myClick>Resolver</a> <!-- using a local reference to <a> -->

<div>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

`app.component.ts`

```js
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs';
import { exhaustMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('myClick') clickButton!: ElementRef; // local reference

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    fromEvent(this.clickButton.nativeElement, 'click')
      .pipe(exhaustMap(() => this.router.navigate(['resolver'])))
      .subscribe();
  }
}
```

If you check the Network tab, you will see just a few HTTP calls thanks to `exhaustMap`

Comment: @BizzyBob, I have updated my answer